# How do I get a specific token balance from a user's wallet? Then set state based on that balance to create conditional renders?

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, metamask, nft

I'm looking to get a specific token balance from a user's address after they log in with metamask then use that balance to create a state. Then I can use that state to have conditionally render the navbar and subsequent page.

How do I do that? And where do I put it? I'm new very new to web dev so looking for any help or guidance, thanks!

https://github.com/zedinstead/NFT-frontend

Answer (score 0):

Could you be more specific about the code? I'm reading your github repo, and I could manage to find a certain `getBalance` function. Would that be the function that gets the users's token balance? And where would you like to display it?

From what I gather, you could perhaps create something like this in the component you want to display the balance:

```
const [balance, setBalance] = useState()

useEffect(() => {
        GetBalance().then((bal) => setBalance(bal))
    }, [])
```

With this you may then use the `balance` state constant wherever you like.

Comment: I need to first pull the token balance from the address(account) that is signed in. I've seen some answers to this out there but not sure where to implement it, I think it would look something like this: `var tokenInst = new web3.eth.Contract(tokenABI,tokenAddress);


    tokenInst.methods.balanceOf('0x260c25f991171850f48889eb9d8aF11998D20c30').call().then(function (bal) {
        console.log(bal);
     })`